# Can i send real file using MockMultipartFile?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have simple controller.

```
@PostMapping()
public Integer uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    return service.readFileFromExcel(file);
}
```

And i want to write integration test for it. I've read about MockMultipartFile and i've seen some examples, but they are too simple like

```
MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "hello.txt", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, "Hello, World!".getBytes());
```

But do I have some way to send real file instead `"Hello, World!".getBytes()` from resourses directory?

Comment: I guess my question was not too clear. That i want is to write test for this controller

Answer (score 3):

`MockMultipartFile` has a [constructor which uses an InputStream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html#MockMultipartFile-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-).

> public MockMultipartFile(String name,
>
> InputStream contentStream)
>     throws IOException Create a new MockMultipartFile with the given content. Parameters: name - the name of the file
>
> contentStream - the content of the file as stream 
>   Throws: IOException
>   - if reading from the stream failed

So you can put in an FileInputStream

```
MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file",new FileInputStream("FileName"));
```

Comment: thank you but java.io.FileNotFoundException: hello.xlsx (The system cannot find the file specified)